# This is the question about integration. I want to know how to approach this question.

Tags: integration

[image: This is the question]

[image: This is my approach, but it doens't give me answer.]

My solution makes same loop, which eventually makes the equation as 0 = 0 form.

Comment: Illegible. Take the time to properly write your question using the tools available in this forum or begone.

Comment: this is you 5th question. You should post your question formatted with  LaTeX.

Comment: THe rightmost expression on the top line, what did you do there?  It's hard to read and I can't think of a move that looks like it.

Comment: Thank you guys ! I don't know how to use calculating program though. Is there anyone who can teach me how to use LaTeX? And, this is the third days to use this website. I'm sorry to make all of you confused :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint:
$$u=\sqrt{x}$$
$$du=\frac1{2u}dx$$
$$2udu=dx$$
$$7\int\frac{1}{u^4+u^3}*2udu$$
$$7\int\frac{2u}{u^4+u^3}du$$
And there's your rational function

Comment: Thank you for your answering !

Answer (score 1):

As answered by ASKASK, using $x=u^2$, $$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+x\sqrt x}=2\int\frac{du}{u^3+u^2}$$ Now, use partial fraction decomposition to get $$\frac{1}{u^3+u^2}=\frac{1}{u^2(u+1)}=\frac{2}{u^2}+\frac{2}{u+1}-\frac{2}{u}$$and then integrate each piece. When done, go back to $x$ since $u=\sqrt x$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 7\int \frac{1}{x^2+x\sqrt{x}}\ dx $$
Let $u=\sqrt{x}$, then
$$ du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx $$
So now we have
$$ 14\int \frac{u}{u^4+u^3}\ du=14\int \frac{1}{u^3+u^2}\ du $$
The next step is to simplify the integrand via partial fraction decomposition
$$ 14\int \frac{1}{u^2}du+14\int \frac{1}{u+1}du-14\int \frac{1}{u}du $$
Can you take it from here?